# Asp .net Website deployment using jenkins

Tags: asp.net, jenkins, deployment

I am trying to deploy mvc.net website using jenkins to my local IIS server, for the same I had written windows execute bath command as (also I am trying to create web deploy package zip file in command mode) :

```
"C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe" "TestJenkins\TestJenkins.csproj" /T:Build;Package /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath="obj\RELEASE" /p:DeployIisAppPath="http://my local address" /p:VisualStudioVersion=14.0 /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:PackageLocation="obj/Release/Package/TestJenkins.zip"
```

and I used this commands for deployment :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:package="TestJenkins\obj\Release\Package\TestJenkins.zip" -dest:auto,computerName=my computer name -allowUntrusted=true
```

I faced to this error :

```
Info: Adding sitemanifest (sitemanifest).
Info: Creating application (http://my local address) Info: Adding virtual 
path (http://my local address) Error Code: ERROR_SITE_DOES_NOT_EXIST More 
Information: Site 'http:' does not exist
```

any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is a real scenario or just a proof of concept?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to set `DeployIisAppPath` parameter to the name of your website in IIS instead of url

Two scenarios:

1. For a separate website in IIS, the `DeployIisAppPath` will be **name** of your IIS website e.g. `TestJenkinsWeb`
2. For deploying as an application under a website e.g. `Default website` then its `DeployIisAppPath` should be set to `Website name/Application name` e.g. `Default Web Site/TestJenkinsApp`